# javascript - blank space validation

Tags: javascript

```
function validation(reg) {
    str = document.reg;
    if (str.name.value == "") {
        alert("Enter your name");
        str.name.focus();
        return false;
    }
```

Validation will working fine if input is empty.

Problem

1. User can enter a blank space on the first.
2. Also user can enter space only on the name.

How to prevent it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here are some trim functions.

http://www.somacon.com/p355.php

and using it

```
function validation(reg) {
    str = document.reg;
    if (str.name.value.trim() == "") {
        alert("Enter your name");
        str.name.focus();
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: It is good to be double sure when you are validating. If you are validating str and it is not defined yet, it will throw an error as trim is a String method and not available on undefined. A good approach will be if(str && !str.trim())

Answer (score 3):

Test the length of the value with all spaces removed.

```
if (str.name.value.replace(/\s+/g, '').length == 0) {
```

Comment: the Best of ALL

Comment: Perfect solution! Does the trick in one line of code.

Answer (score 2):

The code for checking blank space...
if it does then alert comes....

```
function title_validate()
{

       var flag=0;
       var strText = document.f1.title.value;
       if (strText!="")
       {
       var strArr = new Array();
       strArr = strText.split(" ");

       if(strArr.length > 1)
       {
       flag=1;

       }


       }

       if(document.f1.title.value == "" || flag == 1 )
       {        //document.getElementById('t1').style.display="block";//for span alert!!
               alert("shouldn't be blank or contain blank space!!");
               document.f1.title.value="";
               document.f1.title.focus();
               return false;
       }
       return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For checking leading blank space:

```
<html>
<head><TITLE></TITLE>
<script>
function title_validate()
{

       var flag=0;
       var strText = document.f1.title.value;
       if (strText!="")
       {
       var strArr = new Array();
       strArr = strText.split("");

       if(strArr[0]==" ") // this is the the key part. you can do whatever you want here!
       {
       flag=1;
       }


       }

       if(document.f1.title.value=="" || flag == 1 )
       {        alert("shouldn't be blank or contain blank space at the Bewgining!!");
               document.f1.title.value="";
               document.f1.title.focus();
               return false;
       }
       return true;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="f1">
<input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="">
<input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="button" onclick="return title_validate()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use this test instead:

```
if (!s.match(/\w/)) {
  // ohnoes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks 'wombleton'
Here it is. Simple one.

```
<script>
function CheckData()
{
  with(document.frmRecord)
  {
   if(txtUserName.value.match(/\ /)) {
   alert("Please Select a Username without Spaces");
   txtUserName.focus();
   txtUserName.value="";
   return false;
}
  }
  return true;
}
</script>

<form name="frmRecord" onSubmit="return CheckData()">
<label>User Name <span>(no spaces)</span></label>
<input type"text" class="textbox" style="width:98%;" name="txtUserName" />
</form>
```