# Jquery script for checking if input is not empty. A space button issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I've a script, which validates if input is not empty. It works, but the problem appears if you click a space button. It enables a button, and allows to send an empty input. I wonder, guys, is it possible to upgrade my script and fix this issue?

THE SCRIPT:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

 $('.post_button').attr('disabled',true);

 $('.message').keyup(function(){
    if($(this).val().length !=0){
        $('.post_button').attr('disabled', false);
    }
    else
    {
        $('.post_button').attr('disabled', true);        
    }
 })
 });
```

Comment: But, a space in the input isn't an empty value!

Comment: think you can use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151032/javascript-blank-space-validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

trim the value using `trim()` and then check for the length if you don't want to send just the spaces.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

     $('.post_button').attr('disabled', true);

     $('.message').keyup(function () {
          if ($.trim($(this).val()).length != 0) {
             $('.post_button').attr('disabled', false);
         } else {
             $('.post_button').attr('disabled', true);
         }
     })
 });
```

Use `$.trim($(this).val())` as `$(this).val().trim()` doesn't work in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
(function($) {
    $('.post_button').attr('disabled', true);

    $('.message').keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode != 32 && e.$(this).val().length != 0) {
            $('.post_button').attr('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $('.post_button').attr('disabled', true);
        }
    })
})(jQuery);
```

Here the ASCII code of the key pressed is checked, and if it is 32 (space), post button is kept disabled.